# Display:Flex not supported in Safari?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, safari, cross-browser, displayobject

The drop down menus on this site fire off on hover, and then when active, they appear horizontally by using 'display: flex;' in CSS. Can't figure out how to get this to work with Safari though. It works in Chrome, but not Safari.

www.soakandswim.com/wp/pools <--for reference.

Any insight? Thanks!

Comment: It works on Safari 7.0 only by `-webkit` prefix http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some browsers do not fully support all the CSS3 elements.  Try this:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
```

Comment: `display: -webkit-flex;` fixes thing for OS X Safari. Is there a fix for mobile?

Comment: For mobile Safari you have to prefix `-webkit` to the additional properties, e.g.  `-webkit-align-items: center;`