# Broken site in safari for iPad only

Tags: php, ios, css, wordpress, ipad

I have a never seen problem on my last website.
It's a WordPress site and the theme I made had this problem :

It works fine on all navigators and devices, except on safari for Ipad where only the header of the site (content of the header.php file) is displayed.

I need some one to explain me what is happening there, or may be tell me if debug tools exist (i dev on windows, and i've got an iPad at home).

A demo of the website is there : http://sylvain-galoustoff.com/delim/
I can also upload my theme on gitHub if needed.

Any help is welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `display: flex;` property you're using looks like it's defaulting to `display: -webkit-box;` and screwing things up.

[image]

Anywhere you call `display: flex`, you'll also want to call `display: -webkit-flex;`. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416445/displayflex-not-supported-in-safari#30314047)

For more info on flexbox and safari [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137085/flexbox-code-working-on-all-browsers-except-safari-why)

Comment: Thank you Ryan, I was thinking that -webkit-box was the safari's equivalent for flex.
I will check for this and i'll tell you.

I 'm still confused that it works fine on iPhone and not and Ipad.

Comment: one more thing : how do you debug on safari iOS ? How did you get that screenshot ?

Comment: I use [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com) for cross browser/mobile testing. Here's a shot of how the site looks on an  [iPhone 6S](http://i.imgur.com/xNeSZdj.jpg)

Comment: Thank you. I made a lot of changes in my CSS files since your answer, I guess it's why it looks scrappy now on iPhone.
I'm still working on it.

It seems like it is not flex rules prefixes that are causing problems, but height with % units in a flex-box.

Thanks again for your help Ryan :)

Comment: @Sylvain71710 you can debug safari on iOS if you have a Mac